# viewed number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

if i have  `Article` Model and  `User` Model.User `:has_many` Articles.

Article Model has a `viewed` cloumn which record the viewed times.

I want to implement it this way:Once user viewed the article ,`@article.viewed` +1.When the user viewed the same article again in one day, the `@article.viewed`won't +1 again(can't +2 for one user per day).how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

So you should ideally keep a "last_viewed" timestamp on the article.

Does the article belong to the User as well? You're only keeping count of the number of times an article is open by it's owner? or You want to keep a count of the number of times any user views any article once a day?

```
article.rb

def view(date = Date.today)
  tap self do |me|
    if self.last_viewed.to_date != date
      self.last_viewed = date
      self.viewed += 1
      self.save
    end
  end
end

articles_controller.rb

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]).try(:view) 
  # Or if this is what you prefer 
  @article = current_user.articles.find(params[:id]).try(:view)
  ...
end
```

Ideally you DO NOT update the db on a GET call (like the article view above) but in your case it is a classic get action and keeping a view count is a supplementary side effect. Find it in your heart to be OKAY with it :) Keep the view functionality in the article model and definitely keep a last_viewed field in the article model.

If however you need to keep tabs between many user and many articles, you probably need a has_many thru relationship with a "Viewership" model which belongs to user, article, view_count, last_viewed columns in that model.